# In C++ the size of arrays must be a constant expression

Tags: c++

I have a question closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178544/c-array-sizes-without-constant-expressions), the difference being that my code sample does not use `new`

I repeat here the question:

On page 11 of *A Tour of C++ (second edition)* is written

> The size of an array must be a constant expression.

And the nearby examples indicate he means C-style arrays, not std::array.

So the following:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  double my_array[argc];
}
```

should not compile, yet does (GCC 9.3.0, `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall`) without warnings.

(This question has a partial answer in [Are variable length arrays there in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013444/are-variable-length-arrays-there-in-c) I did not find it because I did not know/forgot about the terminology *variable length array*. Below I complete this with an answer to my own question that gives a way to force GCC to comply with current ISO.)

Answer (score 2):

OK, that's a specificity of the compiler I use, GCC: it implements by defaults VLA (Variable Length Arrays) even though this is not part of the C++17 standard.
In fact there is a mention of this in Barry's answer (accepted answer) to [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178544/c-array-sizes-without-constant-expressions), to be found in his footnote.

With the option `-pedantic-errors` the compilation does fail, as expected.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the C++ standard only requires a compiler to refuse to compile code in one case: when it encounters a `#error` directive. In all other cases, a conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic, and then it can continue to compiler the code, with an implementation-specific meaning.